# Is there any alternative ways to create communication between Android and Computer via USB but not using Android Debug Bridge?

Tags: android, .net, usb, adb

I want to send and recevice data between .NET application and Android Device by using USB. However, due to the security concerns, I do not desire to use Android Debug Bridge (USB debugging).

Is there any possible way to send and receive data from Android Device to my .NET application on computer by using USB ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider an encrypted network connection first?

Comment: It's because of security concern too. Clients(people) will use Android devices but we do not want anyone to access our device in a malicious way. What I mean is that we do not want our android devices in our network.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this particular cat, let me name two:

- **Simple message files via MTP**. Pro: Easiest to implement and widest possible client support. Con: High latency. Good, if you have few requests with a bigish payload each.
- **USB networking via CDC-ECM**. Pro: Allows easy extension to full networking. Con: Not so broad client suppoort. Good, if you have full control over the hardware.

The prevalent problem is, that the fragmentation of Android allows you to assume only a very low baseline.

I do recommend, that you revisit the encrypted network connection option: It should be quite trivial to create a minimal network consisting only of the Android device and a single partner - e.g. by pluging a WLAN access point directly into a secondary network interface of the workstation - and by being associated to a special WLAN you make sure, that the device at this point is not connected to a different WLAN or mobile network.

This will not only be easiest, but also give you the best starting point if you want to upgrade to a broader network later on.